# Why I got two quotation marks in CSV file when I export it by Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

This sentence in my original json file [image: original json file]

> \n\nStarts off with \"what is HTML\" and some other basic stuff.

```
import pandas as pd 

fileNameInput = input('Enter data file name (data file must be in \'data\' folder): ')
path = 'data/'+fileNameInput

data = pd.read_json(path, lines=True)
data = data[['overall', 'reviewText']]

data['reviewText'] = data['reviewText'].replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True) #replace all blank space with a single space

print(data.iloc[1,1])

fileNameOutput = fileNameInput.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
data.to_csv('data/'+fileNameOutput, index=False)
```

I use print method to print this sentence to the console and it comes up with only one quotation mark [image: print this sentence]

> Starts off with "what is HTML" and some other basic stuff.

But when I open csv file I see there are two quotation marks [image: csv file]

> Starts off with ""what is HTML"" and some other basic stuff.

Anyone who knows how to fix it please help me!
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Because this is how quotation marks are encoded in CSV. Removing them breaks the file; that's not a "fix". If you just want a plain text file, save as text, not CSV.

Comment: @tripleee wow! This is a new knowledge that I learned today, When I import this csv file to my python and print it, I got only one quotation mark. Thank you!!!